# Capability inheritable for system() call in C/C++

Tags: linux, c, c++, capabilities

Currently I'm trying to understand capabilities in Linux by reading http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html

I created a small C++ application with the capability `CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH+eip`

The capability works fine for the application. But I have a `system()` call inside

```c
system("cat /dev/mtdX > targetFile");
```

How I can inherit the capability to this call?

**Edit:**

I know that `system()` is driven by `fork()` + `execl()`. In the documentation is mentioned, that with `fork()` the child process get the same capabilities as the parent process. But why is the read capability not inherited?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx to @mosvy I implemented his solution with libcap and it seems to work as expected.

```
void inheritCapabilities()
{
    cap_t caps;
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    if (caps == NULL)
        throw "Failed to load capabilities";
    printf("DEBUG: Loaded Capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));
    cap_value_t cap_list[1];
    cap_list[0] = CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH;
    if (cap_set_flag(caps, CAP_INHERITABLE, 1, cap_list, CAP_SET) == -1)
        throw "Failed to set inheritable";
    printf("DEBUG: Loaded Capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));
    if (cap_set_proc(caps) == -1)
        throw "Failed to set proc";
    printf("DEBUG: Loaded Capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));
    caps = cap_get_proc();
    if (caps == NULL)
        throw "Failed to load capabilities";
    printf("DEBUG: Loaded Capabilities: %s\n", cap_to_text(caps, NULL));

    if (prctl(PR_CAP_AMBIENT, PR_CAP_AMBIENT_RAISE, CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH, 0, 0) == -1)
        throw "Failed to pr_cap_ambient_raise!    Error: " + errno;
}

main() {
    inheritCapabilities();

    char *catargv[5];
    catargv[0] = (char *)"cmd";
    catargv[1] = (char *)"arg1";
    catargv[2] = (char *)"arg2";
    catargv[3] = (char *)"arg3";
    catargv[4] = NULL;

    if (execvp(catargv[0], catargv) == -1)
        throw "Failed! command";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you should get `system(3)` out of the way; unlike what you're suggesting `system(3)` is not just `fork+exec`, but something quite complex, involving changing signal dispositions, waiting for the child and using `/bin/sh` as a wrapper (which may drop or add capabilities depending on its maintainer's whims and assumptions, mess with environment variables, source initialization scripts, and other funny things). Using just `execv*(2)` instead of `system(3)` will get all those spurious complications out of the way.

Second, you should have a deep look at the "Transformation of capabilities during `execve()`" part of the [`capabilities(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) manpage. I'm not going to copy-paste it here, but it basically boils down to: **Capabilities are NOT inherited through execve() unless they're added to the *ambient* set** of the thread (process), and they cannot be added there, unless they're already in the inheritable set of the *thread*. (The "inheritable" capabilities from the file's metadata are just a *mask*, limiting those of the thread).

So, in order the have the capabilities inherited through `execve()` you should **a)** copy them from the *permitted* to the *inheritable* set (which you could do with the [`capset(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/capset.2.html) system call [1]) and **b)** add them to the *ambient* set (which you could do with [`prctl(PR_CAP_AMBIENT, PR_CAP_AMBIENT_RAISE)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html)).

Putting it all together:

```
$ cat capexec.c
#include <sys/prctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/capability.h>
#include <err.h>
int main(int ac, char **av){
        static char *dav[] = { "/bin/bash", 0 };

        struct __user_cap_header_struct hs;
        struct __user_cap_data_struct ds[2];
        hs.version = 0x20080522; /*_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3;*/
        hs.pid = getpid();
        if(syscall(SYS_capget, &hs, ds)) err(1, "capget");
        ds[0].inheritable = ds[0].permitted;
        if(syscall(SYS_capset, &hs, ds)) err(1, "capset");

        if(prctl(PR_CAP_AMBIENT, PR_CAP_AMBIENT_RAISE, CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH, 0, 0)) err(1, "prctl(pr_cap_ambient_raise)");

        av = ac < 2 ? dav : av + 1;
        execvp(*av, av);
        err(1, "execvp %s", *av);
}
$ cc -Wall capexec.c -o capexec

   # as root
# setcap cap_dac_read_search+ip /tmp/capexec

$ ./capexec dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes copied, 0.000299173 s, 1.7 MB/s
```

[1] the docs recommend using the libcap library; parts of this example were canibalized from a hack I've written for an old version of android, where there was no libcap, and many header definitions were missing. converting it to use the libcap wrappers is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thx @mosvy for the good explanation. I started implementing it with libcap. If I add the filecap with CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH+eip, does the i not mean, that it can be inherit? Does it still need to be added to the thread inheritable list?

Comment: Yes, as I already mentioned, the inheritable caps from the binary's metadata are only a mask. Look at the formula from "Transformation of capabilities during execve()" in the linked manpage how `F(inheritable)` is used -- it does not factor into `P'(inheritable)` (the thread's capabilities after the `execve()`.

Comment: Thx @mosvy, I posted the answer based on your input below.